# Guessing Game Java JCreator

Tags: java

1. I have to create a program using the random class in package `java.util`, to generate a number between 1 and 100.
2. The user has to be given a max of 6 attempts to guess a number and if they fail to guess correctly on the 6th attempt then the target number should be displayed. The program needs to provide to the with feedback user indicating if their guess is too high or too low. If the guess is correct the program will say *“Congratulations, Your guess is correct.”*
3. The user should provide their name upon starting a session and this should be stored and used in subsequent record generation.
4. The program should create a session for the user and should allow them to have as many goes as they wish within that session. On each go the program should generate a new random number and provide the user with up to 6 attempts to guess it. When the target number is guessed correctly or 6 attempted have been made the user should be given the choice to quit or have another game/go.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuessANumber3 {
    public static int TARGET = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random R = new Random();
        TARGET = R.nextInt(100);
        String guessString;
        int guess;
        int count = 0;
        int bestScore = 0;
        System.out.println(TARGET);
        do {
            // read in a number from user as a string
            guessString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first integer");
            // convert number from type String to type int
            guess = Integer.parseInt(guessString);
            count++;
            if (guess > TARGET) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess is too high", "Hint",
                                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                if (guess < TARGET) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your guess is too low", "Hint",
                                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
            if (count == 6)
                break;

        } while (guess != TARGET);
        if (guess == TARGET)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You found it with " + count + "guesses.",
                            "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have reached the maximum attempts in this go",
                            "Attention", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        if (count < bestScore)
            bestScore = count;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with part 3 and 4?

Comment: Do you have a specific question abour 3 and 4?

Comment: No the reason for names needing to be stored is so that when the user wishes to terminate their session their performance can be written to a record file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to approach to problem by oop design. From your requirements you have

- User - has a name
- Session - session is for user
- Attempt - done during the game when user guesses
- Game - maximal number of attempts is 6

So in pseudocode

```
   class User
   {
      String name;
   }

   class Session
   {
      User user;
      Game currentGame;

      void startNextGame()
      {
          //create game, when game end, ask to continue
      }
   }

   class Game
   {
      int ties = 6;
      int number;
      Game()
      {
          Random random = new Random();
          number = random.nextInt();
      }

      void play()
      {
         for( int i = 0; i < tries; ++i )                                                               
         {
             Attempt attempt = new Attempt( number );
             attempt.try();
             if( attempt.guessed() )
             {
                //Show guessed
                return;
             }                                                                                                                                                                               
         }
         //show unguessed   
      }
   }

   class Attempt()
   {
      int expectedNumber;
      Attempt( int number )
      {
         expectedNumber = number;
      }

      void try()
      {
         //get guess
      }

      boolean guessed()
      {
        //return result of try
      }
   }

void main()
{
     //getUser
     User user;
     //if I have session for user, getSession, if not create and store ex. map
    //start next game in session
}
```